# When do localizations of presentable (infinity) categories commute?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Suppose that $\mathscr{P}$ is a (locally) presentable $\left(\infty,1\right)$ category (which we can assume WLOG is infinity presheaves on some small $\left(\infty,1\right)$ category) , and $R$ and $S$ are classes of morphisms of $\mathscr{P}$ with respect to which we want to localize. Let us not assume that either $R$ or $S$ are a priori saturated classes. Let $\mathscr{P}_S$ and $\mathscr{P}_R$ denote the full subcategory on $S$-local objects and $R$-local object respectively. Their respective inclusions into $\mathscr{P}$ have left adjoints $L_R$ and $L_S$.

**Question:** On what conditions on $S$ and $R$ (besides $S \subset R$) will $L_R$ map $\mathscr{P}_S$ to itself?

(An answer even for $1$-categories would be very helpful).

**Remark:** I'm most interested in the case where $\mathscr{P}$ is $\infty$-presheaves on a Grothendieck site, $S$ consists of the associated covering sieves, and $R$ is in the essential image of the Yoneda embedding.

Comment: One sufficient condition is to have $S \subseteq R$. No?

Comment: Ok, maybe I should rephrase my question, because I'm not looking for when this is trivially true, but good point.

Comment: Do you have answers for the special cases where $\mathscr{P}$ is just a 1 or 2-category? I am just trying to figure out what sort of sufficient conditions would appeal to you.

Comment: @Vidit: I don't. I have two different results I am trying to prove (for different projects), and both which boil down to showing that two different localizations commute in the above sense. In neither case does $S \subset R$ hold.

Comment: This is a non-trivial thing to consider in general. The only not to difficult conditions I know are of the form `$S$-local objects are preserved by homotopy colimits and $L_R$ can be expressed as an homotopy colimits of functors which preserve $S$-local objects'. The other examples I know are very far from being formal and I would not be able to give a general (and workable) criterium out of them. Maybe it might help if you could be more specific!

Comment: @Denis-Charles: In both cases, the ambient $\infty$-category is $\infty$-presheaves on a site, and the class $S$ is covering sieves (so $S$-local objects are not preserved by colimits), and the class $R$ is in the essential image of the Yoneda embedding. (I'll add this to the question).

Comment: Do you mean that the class $R$ consists of the maps between representables presheaves?

Comment: @Denis-Charles: Yes, that's correct. So, in particular, $\mathscr{P}_R$ is equivalent to $\infty$-presheaves on the simplicial localization of the site $\mathscr{C}$ at those maps.

Comment: This looks like a extreme kind of localization: if the underlying category of the site has a trivial homotopy type (e.g. has a terminal of initial object), $R$-local objects are constant, and you are then essentially asking if constant presheaves are sheaves, aren't you? If you invert only some maps of the sites, you might get more interesting examples, like locally constant presheaves or birational presheaves, and be in the situation where $R$-local objects always are $S$-local.

Comment: @Denis-Charles: I think you are misreading what I wrote. $R$ is IN the essential image of Yoneda, but is not the entire essential image. It's a class of morphisms that I want to invert, so "weak equivalences" if you will.

Comment: OK. But then, you might still want to be more specific: the level of difficulty can still range between rather easy (like any $R$-local object is $S$-local; e.g. take the big Zariski site of a (noetherian) scheme and consider $R$ to be the dense open immersions), to impossible (e.g. take the big Zariski or Nisnevich site over an arbitrary scheme an $R$ the class of projections $X\times\mathbf{A}^1\to X$).

Comment: Ok, I'll send you an email to be more specific. By the way, when you say impossible, do you mean very very difficult, or indeed impossible?

Comment: I mean false with this level of generality. In fact, if we restrict to the smooth Nisnevich site over a perfect field, we can prove that this works for presheaves with additional structures (e.g. presheaves of abelian groups with transfers) but these are non-trivial results. To be more specific, I just mean that all the examples and counter-examples I know (and alluded to in my previous comments) fit in your framework.